# right procedure to check for ether balance in my geth testnet mining node

Tags: mining, testnets

If this is the address of my node:

[image]

which I created with this command:

```
geth --testnet account new
```

then is it correct that I check the ether balance of my account in this way:

[image]

according to my understanding, my node should be mining- if that's the case- would it make sense for my console output to look like this:

[image]

Comment: 1) are you mining on the main net? You're unlikely to find a block there with just a single computer! 2) yes, that is the correct way of checking the balance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can fire up a console and check your mining hash rate like this:

[image]

if it's not `undefined`, `0`, or so on- something obviously wrong- then you're probably mining- some number like I have there is a good sign.

Comment: echo "sha bang #!"